# Android adb pm disable component

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to understand the use of the following command:

```
adb shell pm disable <PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT>
```

For example: I have a test app with package name 'com.example.com.testapp' and it has an activity called 'TestActivity'.

I ran the following from my terminal :

```
./adb shell pm disable com.example.com.testapp/TestActivity
```

From the name of the command, I thought it would disable the activity from launching, but I can launch it fine via adb as follows:

```
./adb shell am start -n com.example.com.testapp/.TestActivity
```

So what does this command disable then ?

Comment: You must be a superuser if you want to disable applications. Are you a superuser? Is your phone/tablet rooted?

Comment: No, my device is not rooted.

Comment: Why doesn't the Android documentation mentioning the requirement about rooting ?

Comment: It's ok to ask if you don't know something. Try to find rooted device, and then try pm disable. If you definitely need to disable something, go to settings->apps, find desired app and disable it. On my HTC this is really simple.

Comment: The Android documentation won't say anything about "rooting" because that is not a method contemplated in the design of Android, and it's only very, very indirectly a method of accomplishing anything that the Android APIs normally deny.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the problem. It has nothing to do whether device is rooted or not.

I command had a missing dot. It should be :

```
./adb shell pm disable com.example.com.testapp/.TestActivity
```

Now if I try to launch the component, it's blocked (the app stops working).